# Firebase Database secure data from project owner

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not talking about security rules. I am developing an app and as a Database owner can see what my users store in my Firebase Realtime Database from console. From Data tab I can see full JSON tree. Can I hide data from me to make my users feel 100% secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to hide the data in the console from the owner of a project. While you *can* grant/deny access to the data for specific services for collaborators, owners can always see all services in the project.

If you want to not be able to see any of the user's data, you'll need to use some form of end-to-end encryption where the key is not stored in Firebase.